# xxx not identified as internal or external command

Tags: java

Sry for bringing this question again as its most common solution would be to include path.. I am trying to implement a class and after implementation it displays the following

```
java -classpath java-getopt-1.0.8.jar;3dm-0.1.0.jar;xerces.jar tdm.
tool.TreeDiffMerge
3DM XML Tree Differencing and Merging Tool version 0.1.0 build 0.1.0-2006.02.07.
12.26.44
Usage: 3dm [options] {-m base branch1 branch2|-d base branch1 |-p base patch} [o
utfile]
Use the -m (or --merge) option to merge the files base, branch1 and branch2
Use the -d (or --diff) option to diff the files base and branch1
Use the -p (or --patch) option to patch the file base with the file patch
The options are:
-e, --editlog[=logfile]
   Log edit operations to logfile, default edit.log
-c, --copythreshold=bytes
   Threshold for considering a duplicate structure to be a copy. Default value i
s 128 bytes
```

Now a exe is not created ..Do u know wht the pblm might be.. Or can u suggest ways to solve this issue ?

Comment: 1.) What do you mean by "implement a class"? Do you mean "execute a class"? 2.) What does the error message in the topic title have to do with your problem? You never mention that message again. 3.) Why do you expect an exe to be created? 4.) What goal do you try to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question title.

It's clear from the message that you aren't invoking the tool properly, and need to provide command-line arguments to the tool in order to tell it what to do.  E.g.:

```
java -classpath java-getopt-1.0.8.jar;3dm-0.1.0.jar;xerces.jar tdm.tool.TreeDiffMerge -p base patch
```

If you've implemented your own main class and want to invoke it, you'll need to provide the classname on the command line instead of `tdm.tool.TreeDiffMerge`.  (And if you want an `exe` to be created, hopefully your class does this because Java has absolutely nothing to do with creating exes inherently.)